# Attribute to indicate string should be serialized using JRaw

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there an attribute to indicate a string property of an object should be serialized using `JRaw` in JSON.NET?

```cs
public class MyClass {
  public string MyJsFunction {get;set}
}
```

`MyJsFunction` should be serialized using `JRaw` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800721).

Update:

I have a class `JavaScriptConverter`:

```cs
public static class JavaScriptConverter
{
  public static IHtmlContent SerializeObject(
    object value
  )
  {
    using var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);

    var serializer = new JsonSerializer
    {
      ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };


    jsonWriter.QuoteName = false;
    jsonWriter.QuoteChar = '\'';
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);

    return new HtmlString(stringWriter.ToString());
  }
}
```

Based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77933179/attribute-to-indicate-string-should-be-serialized-using-jraw#comment137392241_77933179) by @dbc I created another class `RawStringConverter`:

```cs
public class RawStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
  public override bool CanConvert(
    Type objectType
  )
  {
    return objectType == typeof(string);
  }

  public override bool CanRead => false;

  public override object ReadJson(
    JsonReader reader,
    Type objectType,
    object existingValue,
    JsonSerializer serializer
  )
  {
    return JRaw.Create(reader)
      .ToString();
  }

  public override void WriteJson(
    JsonWriter writer,
    object value,
    JsonSerializer serializer
  )
  {
    writer.WriteRawValue((string)value);
  }
}
```

I created a test:

```cs
public class TestObject
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [JsonConverter(typeof(RawStringConverter))]
  public string OnClick { get; set; }
}



public class SomeTest {
  [Fact]
  public void ShouldSerializeRaw()
  {
    var result = JavaScriptConverter.SerializeObject(
        new
        {
          Name = "Jane",
          OnClick = "function() { return 'Hello'; }"
        }
      )
      .ToString();
    result.ShouldBe("{name: 'Jane',onClick: function() { return 'Hello'; }}");
  }
}
```

However, the result is still:

```
"{name:'Jane',onClick:'function() { return \'Hello\'; }'}"
```

Comment: You could apply a custom converter.  E.g. `[JsonConverter(typeof(RawStringConverter))] public string MyJsFunction {get;set}` where the converter comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797460/3744182) to [How to deserialize dodgy JSON (with improperly quoted strings, and missing brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46788778/3744182).  Does that count as "an attribute"?

Comment: Have you considered a custom converter and creating a custom class to encapsulate your function that you converter then serializes using JRaw?

Comment: @dbc thanks, I updated my question based on your comment.

Comment: In your updated question, where are you applying `RawStringConverter`?  I don't see it in `JsonSerializerSettings.Converter` and I don't see it applied via attributes to `public string MyJsFunction {get;set}`.

Comment: @dbc I updated the question again (the part where the test is shown now contains the `TestObject` class.

Comment: `new { }` creates an [anonymous type object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types).  Since you want to create an instance of `TestObject` you need to do `new TestObject {  }`.

Comment: I also tried to add `serializer.Converters.Add(new RawStringConverter());` in the `JavaScriptConverter` but then the `Name` property value is also serialized without quotes.

Comment: @dbc ah, yes. Now it works! Thanks so much. Please post an answer so I can mark it as solution.